# Detecting a change in BizTalk Server configuration

Tags: biztalk

Is there a way (without actually keeping a state in a external application and scanning the configuration database) to detect a configuration change in BizTalk Server? 
I know there are timestamps for changes for the different artifact in the configuration database but are there any sort of general flag that indicate a change?

I'd like to for example kick of a process as a change occurs and for example log current configuration - without adding triggers or similar things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no 'change notification' built into the product nor is there an 'official' way to track or identify changes.

Of course, there are various techniques you can use to identify changes such as monitoring timestamps, examine the SQL Logs, etc, but that would be a custom implementation.

BizTalk 360 has a robust auditing feature that might cover what you're really asking for.

From experiance, this question of 'tracking changes' is driven by governance scenarios where controls and access are more open then they should be.  That's a management problem.

Comment: Ok. Just making sure I didn't miss any obvious. 

The request is driven by a big lack of functionality in BizTalk if you ask me. There really should be a more standard built-in controlled way of configuring BizTalk and not just have "BizTalk Administrators" as default. There should be an easy way of letting people onLY see and have access to for example one application along with good audit information on changes.

Comment: Then BizTalk 360 will likely be the solution you're looking for.  It's reasonable priced and gives a much finer level of control than the OOB tools.